# Android Studio - Automotive emulator not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to have possibility to launch automotive emulator via my AS. What should I do ?

Currently I have no such option.

My AVD manager, see categories.

[image: my conf]

Expected view
[image: Expected]

I can create the device tho, but it does not appear in the device definition list.
[image]

Comment: Which version of Android studio are you using, I am facing the same problem

Comment: using version 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable automotive features in Android Studio.

Please follow the instructions from https://developer.android.com/training/cars/start, paragraph "Enable automotive features in Android Studio"

Comment: Is not working for me on AS 4.2 canary and 4.0 stable.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the instructions [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/automotive-getting-started/index.html#2).

All you need is that line:

```
<entry key="npw.templates.automotive" value="true" />
```